Merge [anonymity] into [privacy]
I think that anonymity and privacy collect the same topic of questions and should be merged. Privacy seems to be the more accurate term, therefore I would make anonymity a synonym of privacy.
What do you think?

Sounds good to me.

Went ahead with the merge in agreement with Nick and Stephen, and added a new tag excerpt in the same go.
